# Save CSV with + Sign Swift 4

Tags: swift, excel, csv

I was trying to save a CSV file with a "+" sign in it but for some reason the + sign just goes away. Below is my code and a photo of the CSV file opened up in Excel.

Save CSV Code:

```
let fileName = dateString + "-Payments.csv"

    var csvText = "Name,Money,Date\n"

    var newLine = "Test 1, +400, 11-10-18\n"
    csvText.append(newLine)
    newLine = "Test 2, +400, 11-10-18\n"
    csvText.append(newLine)
    newLine = "Test 3, +400, 11-10-18\n"
    csvText.append(newLine)
    newLine = "Test 4, +400, 11-10-18\n"
    csvText.append(newLine)
    newLine = "Test 5, +400, 11-10-18\n"

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

        do {

            try csvText.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)

            //Code to Present UIActivityViewController has been removed.

        } catch {

            print("\(error)")

        }

    }
```

CSV File:

[image: CSV File in Excel]

Can any of you guys help? Thanks.

Edit:

The Following is Code that Produces a Corrupt CSV File. Any Ideas?

```
let fileName = dateString + "-Clients.xls"

    var csvText = "Name,Location,Date,Price,Days-Left\n"

    for user in paymentArray {

        let newLine = "\(user.name),\(user.location),\(user.date),\(user.money),\(user.daysLeft)\n"

        csvText.append(newLine)

    }

    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

        do {

            try csvText.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)

            let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: [])

            vc.excludedActivityTypes = [
                UIActivityType.assignToContact,
                UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
                UIActivityType.postToFlickr,
                UIActivityType.postToVimeo,
                UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,
                UIActivityType.postToTwitter,
                UIActivityType.postToFacebook,
                UIActivityType.openInIBooks
            ]

            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } catch {

            print("\(error)")

        }

    }
```

Payment User:

```
struct PaymentUser {

var name: String = ""

var money: String = ""

var location: String = ""

var date: String = ""

var daysLeft: Int = 0
```

}

Picture:

[image]

Raw CSV:

```
Name,Location,Date,Price,Days Left
Name Here,Loc,2/2/18,300,22
Name Here,Loc,2/4/18,300,24
Name Here,Loc,1/12/18,1050,1
Name Here,Loc,2/3/18,300,23
```

BTW, Payment Array is an Array of PaymentUser

Comment: Totally unrelated to your issue but you have the "Date" and "Money" columns (or titles) reversed.

Comment: Haha, That happened because this isn't my actual code, only an example, and I forgot to change that.

Comment: In what way is it corrupt? Keep in mind that if any value has a comma or a newline, you nee to put the value in quotes. And if the value has a quote, you need to escape it with another quote character.

Comment: When I open up the file, it shows up really weirdly. I added it to my post.

Comment: Show the first few lines of the raw CSV file in your question.

Comment: The CSV looks fine. Maybe you imported it incorrectly into Excel.

Comment: That’s exactly what I was thinking. Could be an issue with Excel. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If possible try checking my Created Project for reference

https://github.com/RockinGarg/CSV-FIle-Swift4.git

Expected output :

[image]

Will append new Lines As same as your Code

[image]

Comment: Looked at it. Thanks!

Comment: If you face any issue with code written just tell me I will try to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV is fine. But there is no reason to use a `+` with positive numbers. Your "issue" is simply that Excel (and most apps) won't show a `+` before positive numbers. Of course you should be able to format such cells in Excel but that sort of formatting isn't part of a CSV file.

In other words. Everything is working just fine.

Comment: Oh ok, so if I use a negative number and put a '-' in front of it, Excel will show it? Also, is there any way to save an xlxs file in iOS and color the rows? The XLXS Reader/Writer on Github seems promising but the swift header for it is only for the reader, not the writer.

Comment: Yes, it will work with negative numbers. Try it. Creating an xlsx file is really hard. Library recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I added some extra code to my post, that code when run produces a csv that is corrupt. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When working with csv files and strings this function might be useful otherwise it would jump to the new column if there is a "," in the string. It changes all "," to ";" or what else you want.

```
var csvValues: [String] = []
for i in 0..<csvValues.count {
    let replacedString = String(csvValues[i].map { $0 == "," ? ";" : $0 })
    csvValues[i] = replacedString
    csvString += csvValues[i] + "\n"

}
```